# mongodb - aggregate lookup without local

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So I have two `ObjectId`s that are in different collections, which I would like to be merged as an output. So it's like using the `$lookup` function without any local fields. Without an aggregate I could simply do two `.findOne`, but that would require two API calls (which would create two connections). Is it possible to achieve it in one?

So without the aggregation it would just look something like this:

```
let main_document =
    db.findOne({
        _id: ObjectId(first)
    })

let subdocument =
    db.findOne({
        _id: ObjectId(second)
    })

main_document.subdocument = subdocument

return main_document
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

You don't need to specify the `localField` in the newer [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) syntax. Just use `$match` inside the sub pipeline of [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)  aggregation

```
db.main_document.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId(first) }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "subdocument",
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId(second) }},
    ],
    "as": "subdocument"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$subdocument" }
])
```